there is a subscript bug in beamer
I am making my slides with beamer but when I put two mathematical modes (??) it fails and I tried everything and I can't find the answer to solve it.
- Objetivo general
    - Al$_2$

this works fine, but when I put the second component
- Objetivo general
    - Al$_2$O$_3$

it colapses and doesn't subscripts

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please consider providing a full and compilable miminal working example that shows the error and also makes clear your document set up.

It seems that you like to wrote chem expressions. For this exist specialized packages, for example mhchem. Using it you can simple write \ce{AL2} or \ce{Al2O3}.

If I guess enough code to compile your fragments, they work without error. Please always include a reproducible test file in your questions.

I couldn't reproduce this error in a minimal beamer document, so it's not a “bug in beamer”.

Try $\text{Al}_2\text{O}_3$, but the Chem packages are the way to go

It seems that you like to wrote chem expressions. For this exist specialized packages, for example mhchem. Using it you can simple write your expressions as:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}  % <---

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Chemistry expressions}
\ce{Al2} or \ce{Al2O3}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}





But it isn't clear whether your markup is semantically correct, even though it is TeXnically valid.
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Objetivo general
    \item Al$_2$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Objetivo general
    \item Al$_2$O$_3$
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

